# KeyError: tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_6:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

Can you please explain the problem below?  Here is my code fragment in my python notebook:

```
word2int = {}
int2word = {}

for i,word in enumerate(words):
    word2int[word] = i
    int2word[i] = word

def euclidean_dist(vec1, vec2):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((vec1-vec2)**2))

def find_closest(word_index, vectors):
    min_dist = 10000 # to act like positive infinity
    min_index = -1
    query_vector = vectors[word_index]
    for index, vector in enumerate(vectors):
        if euclidean_dist(vector, query_vector) < min_dist and not np.array_equal(vector, query_vector):
            min_dist = euclidean_dist(vector, query_vector)
            min_index = index
    return min_index

Z = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
find_closest_word = int2word[find_closest(word2int[Z], vectors)]

# Create SignatureDef metadata for the model
classification_inputs = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(Z)
classification_outputs_classes = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(find_closest_word)

classification_signature = (
      tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
          inputs={
              tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS:
                  classification_inputs
          },
          outputs={
              tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
                  classification_outputs_classes
          },
          method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME))
```

Here is the error message when I run the code fragment above:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-016dad8c7403> in <module>()
     12     return min_index
     13 Z = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
---> 14 find_closest_word = int2word[find_closest(word2int[Z], vectors)]

KeyError: <tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_7:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=string>
```

#### Updated question:

How can I convert a string tensor `Z` to a python string so that it can be used as index in `word2int`?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this problem? I have a very similar issue and I still can't find a way to solve it.

Comment: I have the same issue, the answer available right now is not really helpful. Would be nice to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I guess you think `Z` is the word you pass as input to the network. It isn't, since you define it as `Z = tf.placeholder(tf.string)`. Z is thus a **placeholder** object that will *eventually* be filled with a string in your `feed_dict` when you run the graph in a `tf.Session` instance by calling its `run()` method.

Since your `word2int` dictionary is just a string-to-index dict, you get the `KeyError` when you try to use the placeholder as a key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've just update my question above for more detail.  Yes. I want `Z` to be the input parameter and `int2word[find_closest(word2int[Z], vectors)]` to be the output parameter.  How can fix word2int to accept `Z` and fix int2word to be output?

Comment: I guess my question above is not quite clear.  Let me ask again: How can I convert a string tensor `Z` to a python string so that it can be used as index in `word2int`?